# Splash Screen between forms

Tags: vb.net, splash-screen

One of the forms on my application takes a while to load.

I need a splash screen that pops up while the form loads. Unfortunately I don't even know where to start on this one as I can't seem to find anyone using splash screen between forms, only when loading application so I couldn't find any ideas.

Can anyone give me a clue?

Regards

Comment: `One of the forms ... takes a while to load.` Rather than try to distract the user, you might want to spend the time and effort streamlining the code

Comment: Unfortunately that is not an option as the delay in loading the form seems to be related to the database queries and the database location rather than the code. I'm currently trying a new form with a loading icon to show while the form loads, but I'm not being able to make the "please wait" form disappear instantly when the delayed form shows up. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your project > Add > New Item  > Splash Screen

Comment: That is not the problem, that is done. My problem is, how do I get it to show when it is needed? I do not need it when launching the application I need it between "form2" and "form3"

Comment: @OMGSOMETAL : A splash screen works just like any other form. Call `Show()` or `ShowDialog()` whenever you want it to become visible to the user.